# How to update setting in app.config.exe file runtime

Tags: c#

I am trying to update value of a particular setting in app.config.exe at run time. But as per my code its getting updating in vshost32.exe file which seem to duplicate as app.config.exe. My code is given below

```
 private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

     Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

                            ConfigurationSectionGroup applicationSectionGroup = config.GetSectionGroup("applicationSettings");
                            string d = applicationSectionGroup.Sections[0].ToString(); ;
                            ConfigurationSection applicationConfigSection = applicationSectionGroup.Sections["Secure_Browser_CS_Version.Properties.Settings"];
                            ClientSettingsSection clientSection = (ClientSettingsSection)applicationConfigSection;

                            //Encryption Key Configuration Setting
                            SettingElement applicationSetting = clientSection.Settings.Get("NavigateURL");
                            applicationSetting.Value.ValueXml.InnerXml = txtURL.Text;

                            applicationConfigSection.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                            config.Save();

}
```

// app.config.exe

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="MyApplicationName.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <MyApplicationName.Properties.Settings>

            <setting name="NavigateURL" serializeAs="String">
                <value></value>
            </setting>

        </MyApplicationName.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are doing everything correct, but since you are running using vshost.exe, this is the exe whose configuration is updated.
To run without vshost, uncheck the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" checkbox in Project prroperties -> Debug tab:
[image]

Comment: i did the same but still my app.config file not getting updated with new value

Comment: Ya i got it...the new value is getting updated in exe file so i can not see in my project path... Thanks a lot !!!